# Preventing from default behavior even though preventDafault() method has not been called yet

Tags: javascript, preventdefault, event-bubbling

In this piece of code there is an element called container and a checkbox in it. There is
an EventListener on the container which calls a function if a click event happens on its
child or itself. This function prevents browser from performing default action when
this event happens. So when the checkbox is clicked it does not toggle its checked state.

```js
document.querySelector(".container").addEventListener("click" , function(e){
  e.preventDefault() 
})
```

```css
.container{
  padding:2rem;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```

I expected the checkbox to be checked when it's clicked because it happens before telling
the browser to prevent from default behavior.
That function will be called on the bubbling phase of the event and at that point
the checkbox is already clicked, I don't understand why before the function is called
the checkbox prevents default behavior?

Comment: Calling preventDefault() during any stage of event flow cancels the event, meaning that any default action normally taken by the implementation as a result of the event will not occur. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: "*it happens before telling the browser to prevent from default behavior*" - no. It happens after the event has been fired and processed by all event handlers. It does not happen between the capturing and bubbling phases of event propagation.